# How to separate csv column that contains "Lastname, Firstname" into two different csv columns using bash?

Tags: bash, csv

I have a csv with two columns. One column containing "Last Name, First Name" and a number associated with the name. I would like the 1st column with the oddly concatenated column to be separated and have the CSV contain headers like this: First Name, Last Name, Associated Number

The csv file currently looks like this:

```
"Dinkleberg, Mark", 245
"Persoli, Kyle", 246
"Liang, Emily", 247
```

The end result I want it to look like is this

```
Mark, Dinkleberg, 245
Kyle, Persoli, 246
Emily, Liang, 247
```

The way I have been achieving my result is by using the split column by comma feature in Excel and replacing the spaces associated with the first name with nothing. It is a really extremely tedious process and would like to see how I could write a solution in Bash.

Comment: Just remove the `"`? `tr -d \"` ?

Comment: We would love to see whatever code or research you have so far, so readers can build on it in an answer.

Comment: @halfer I managed the get my results by using excel and textedit replace and got what I wanted in the most unorthodox way. Hence I dont have a script. Im sure there is like simple bash line out there to achieve what I want  hence why i asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
awk -F'[ ",]' '{print $4, $2, $7}' OFS=', ' file
```

Or with [tr](/questions/tagged/tr) and `csvcut` :

```
tr -d '"' file | csvcut -d ',' -c 2,1,3
```

### OUTPUT:

```
Mark, Dinkleberg, 245
Kyle, Persoli, 246
Emily, Liang, 247
```

This will not work if there's extra spaces in first or second name